# Submitting form with disabled and read only fields - nothing comes though

Tags: jquery, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have a form that I need to disable some of the fields from certain users while others can fill and edit them all so what I have is as follows:

```
$('.adminOnlyField').attr("readonly","true");
$('.adminOnlyField').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
```

So because of this when the form is submitted nothing is coming though to the controller to process the changes. e.g. $_POST is empty ($this->request->data in cakePHP), as soon as I remove these lines the data is submitting again.

Any idea how I can get around this? I am using cakePHP but I don't think this should matter.

Thanks

Comment: Is it necessary to show those fields if the user can't change anything? Why not remove them for users that should not modify them?

Comment: Yes it is a requirement to show the fields as the users who are not able to edit the fields still need to see the details / progress of the form. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`.prop()` is used this way:

```
$('.adminOnlyField').prop('disabled', true);
```

But i can't understand why are you `disabling` it and also making it `readonly`. If your inputs are `disabled` or `readonly` then how would you input values in it manually.

Comment: I have .prop('disabled', true) setup for the dropdowns, it seems if I just have .attr("readonly","true"); the dropdowns are still selectable.

Answer (score 0):

If you disabled the fields then those will not get posted with the form. If you just want to restrict them to be edited, just mark them as readonly.. just add following line and remove the disabling.

```
$('.adminOnlyField').attr("readonly","true");
```

> You should keep the select element disabled but also add another
>   hidden input with the same name and value.
>
> If you reenable your SELECT, you should copy it's value to the hidden
>   input in an onchange event.